# Error while testing Insert row in embedded hsqldb with jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, testing, hsqldb, spring-jdbc

I am testing create method for my application .
In test I have embedded hsql db , and using Spring jdbcTemplate

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:/sql/db/db-schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:/sql/db/db-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

where db-data.sql is

```
INSERT INTO C_ContactType(name) VALUES ('bob_eng991');
INSERT INTO C_ContactType(name) VALUES ('bob_eng2');
INSERT INTO C_ContactType(name) VALUES ('bob_eng3');
INSERT INTO C_ContactType(name) VALUES ('bob_eng422');
```

db-schema.sql is

```
  CREATE TABLE C_ContactType (
  contactTypeId INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  name VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
  deletedOn DATETIME,
  deletedBy INT
  );
```

and my test is

```
@Test
void test_createClassifier() {

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/classifiers/{category}",  "ContactType")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .param("languageId", String.valueOf(3))
            .content("{ \"name\": \"bob_eng100\"}".getBytes()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())

}
```

running test I get errors here

```
ResultSet rs = jdbcTemplate.insertWithKey(tablePath,
            insert -> insert.columns(paths.toArray(new Path[paths.size()]))
                    .values(params.toArray(new Object[paths.size()]))
                    .executeWithKeys());
```

where tablePath indicates to "C_ContactType" ,
paths is an ArrayList with my table columns except autoIncrement field ,
and params is an ArrayList with values (except autoIncrement field)

And logs

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: contactTypeId
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Table.getColumnIndex(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Table.getColumnIndexes(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.setGeneratedColumnInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 82 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error show the name of the column requested by the framework. The name is in mixed case `contactTypeId`.

Your table declaration does not have double-quote characters around the table and column names, therefore the names are converted to upper-case by the database engine. You need to change the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE C_ContactType (
"contactTypeId" INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
```

Comment: thanks , i will try it , but I have tests with data update too , and they behave normally

Comment: latest code in HSQLDB SVN /base/trunk should work without changing the table definition